# perl one liners + add empty line after the last line

Tags: linux, perl, shell-scripting, ksh

please advice

what need to change in the perl syntax in order to add new empty line after the last line?

example

```
    IP_INFO=12.23.2.1
    echo IP= |  perl  -pe "s/$/$IP_INFO/" 1>>file
```

.

```
more file

IP=12.23.2.1    <-- last line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
echo IP= |  perl  -pe "s/$/$IP_INFO\n/" 1>>file
```

Comment: I copied it from question (like pkhamre I think) and I added \n.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it with another shell command?

```
IP_INFO=12.23.2.1
echo IP= |  perl  -pe "s/$/$IP_INFO/" 1>>file
echo >> file
```

Comment: not good it must be as part of perl one liners command , I ask to change the perl command not add echo commnad

Comment: @yael okay, sorry for trying to help you find a solution.